# Transfer Many Stata Replaces to R

Tags: r, replace, stata, missing-data

I have a couple thousand lines of Stata code that generally aims to replace negative (missing) values with a proper missing value (`.`) from a peer, and I need to transfer this code to R. To do so, I have taken the code and saved it as a single column of character strings. Replacements essentially look like the following, ad nauseam:

```
replace R04_ADULTTYPE = . if (R04_ADULTTYPE <= -1 )
```

These `R04_` are variables in a data set, so I hope to essentially transfer these lines of Stata to R efficiently.

I have tried taking this and separating/replacing to easily iterate over a list of variables that need replacing, but I am running low on ideas. **Any ideas on how to easily transfer these replaces en masse to R if I have them in the form of a character string data set?** My expected output is essentially conducting many Stata replaces in R, which I have presented in data below.

Dput of the head of the data (`rawMissing`). Thanks!

```
# Data (many Stata replaces
dput(head(rawMissing))
structure(list(replacements = c("replace R04_ADULTTYPE = . if (R04_ADULTTYPE <= -1 )", 
"replace R04R_A_AT0047 = . if (R04R_A_AT0047 <= -1 )", "replace R04R_A_AM0069 = . if (R04R_A_AM0069 <= -1 )", 
"replace R04R_A_AM0065_V2 = . if (R04R_A_AM0065_V2 <= -1 )", 
"replace R04_AM0066 = . if (R04_AM0066 <= -1 )", "replace R04_AM0070 = . if (R04_AM0070 <= -1 )"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

# Expected output would be efficiently conducting these many replaces in R
```

Comment: My understanding is that you want to replace the string and then `eval/parse`  each row to change the variables in the original object.   It is not clear whether these `R04_ADULTTYPE` are columns in another object or not.  As `R` is vectorized, the `if` part can be `ifelse` or` replace`

Comment: Yes, the `R04` are variables in a different context. I hope to simply transfer a ton of Stata lines to R in an efficient way. I could do some string replacements to use `if` or `ifelse`, but I am wondering if this is the best way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Line by line translation may not be the effective way as both languages may have different optimization for each method.  It may be better IMHO to rewrite the code taking the essence

Comment: Kind of what I feared, yeah. Do you think there is an efficient solution by extracting the variable (`R04`), the operator (`<=` or `==`) and the numeric (`-1`) in separate columns, and replacing en masse by iterating over the columns?

Comment: Do you need `library(tidyr);rawMissing %>% extract(replacements, into = c('colnm', 'operator', 'value'), '^[^(]+\\((\\w+)\\s+([[:punct:]]+)\\s+(-?[0-9]+)')`

Comment: Definitely what I think could work, yes! This way, I could use the `value` column as an indicator, replacing a list of missing values by their `operator` and `value`, right? Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: It seems like your first step should be simplifying your Stata code. A couple thousand lines of Stata code for a series of replacements in very inefficient. So far I see your examples take the form of `replace variable = . if (variable <= -1 )`. This can be done in a loop of a few lines.

Comment: I know. As I noted, this Stata is from a peer that I am trying to make much more efficient. Unfortunately, I am well versed in R but not Stata, so this transfer is a bit challenging.

Comment: I posted a solution below.  What is the `.` meaning ?  does it literally translate to the column value or `"."`

Comment: The missing value in `R` is `NA`.  Please check the updated solution

Comment: I believe `.` is Stata's representation of missing values, unlike R's `NA`. The data we have unfortuantely represents missing values as large negative numbers `-9999`, so we need to change those for descriptive statistics.

Comment: @SimonPage ok, sure.  I think my solution should work (though it is not tested on actual data ('df1')

Comment: I think it at least gets me on the right track. Thank you! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may `extract` the column names, operator and the value to be replaced as separate columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
keydat <- rawMissing %>%
     extract(replacements, into = c('colnm', 'operator', 'value'), 
         '^[^(]+\\((\\w+)\\s+([[:punct:]]+)\\s+(-?[0-9]+)')
```

then, using the above data, loop `across` the original dataset say 'df1' by looping `across` the columns specified in the 'keydat' and do the `replace`ments

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(keydat$colnm), ~ 
         {
         op <- keydat$operator[match(cur_column(), keydat$colnm)]
         val <-  keydat$value[match(cur_column(), keydat$colnm)]
         replace(., match.fun(op)(., val), NA)
        


        }))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @akrun's answer would be to write a new R script and then source that script. This may be helpful to, for example, look through the code and to document exactly what has been done (e.g., for replicable data analysis, etc.). I think that the following would generally work where `statareplace.do` is the filename of the original Stata file to be read and `statareplace.R` is the filename of the resulting R script:

```r
fin <- "statareplace.do"
fout <- "statareplace.R"

f <- readLines(fin)
g <- gsub(
    "^\\w+\\s+(\\w+)(\\s+)?=(\\s+)?.+if\\((.+)\\)$", "\\1 = ifelse(\\4", f
)
g <- gsub(
    "^\\w+\\s+(\\w+)(\\s+)?=(\\s+)?(.+) if(\\s+)?\\((.+)\\)$", 
    "\\1 = ifelse(\\6, \\4, \\1),", f
)
g <- gsub("\\.", "NA", g)
g

writeLines(c("library(dplyr)", "df <- df %>%", "mutate(", g, ")"), fout)
source(fout)
```

Comment: A great alternative! I'll be sure to try this as well: thanks!